# Runtime when read to std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have such code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,m;
vector<vector<int>> a, b;

cin >> n >> m;
a.resize(n);
b.resize(n);
for(auto& el : a)
    el.resize(m);
for(auto& el : b)
    el.resize(m);
for(auto& row : a)
    for(auto& el : row)
        cin >> el;
for(auto& row : b)
    for(auto& el : row)
        cin >> el;
}
```

This works fine: read sizes of matrix and 2 such matrices. 
For example, let's read data like this:

```
2 2
4 4
4 5
5 4
4 4
```

The problem is, when I add some additional code (doesn't matter, what it does):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n,m;
vector<vector<int>> a, b;

cin >> n >> m;
a.resize(n);
b.resize(n);
for(auto& el : a)
    el.resize(m);
for(auto& el : b)
    el.resize(m);
for(auto& row : a)
    for(auto& el : row)
        cin >> el;
for(auto& row : b)
    for(auto& el : row)
        cin >> el; // Fail here
cout << "test message\n";

for(int ib = 0; ib < n; ib++)
for(int jb = 0; jb < m; jb++){
    int x = ib + jb;
    for(int i = 0; i < max(n, m); i++)
    {
        if (a[x - i][i] == b[ib][jb])
        {
            a[x - i][i] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't matter, what it does.
It fails with runtime error BEFORE "test message" output. Specially, on my laptop with MinGW compiler it works fine, but on ideone (g++6.3) : https://ideone.com/vl3g4B it fails with 'std::length_error'.

As I understand, this error is possible when I change vector length when iterate on it, but here, I doesn't change anything. Also, I have same error, if change reading from for_each using to double for and push_back() without previous resize.

Any ideas, why it can be so?

Comment: Save you a bit of code: `vector<vector<int>> a` and the loops used to allocate the storage it needs can almost always be replaced with `vector<vector<int>> a(n, <vector<int>(m))`.

Comment: Wow, that's looks great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`x-i` becomes negative when `ib` and `jb` are 0. You can't access a negative index of a vector.

`i` may also happen to be bigger than `m`.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I get runtime error earlier. And, if you see my ideone link - there are such check. I tried to minimize code to reproduce a problem.

Comment: @pashchenkoromak Welcome to undefined behavior land where effect can come before cause.

Comment: Yes, it does matter. The compiler will generate code to fetch the various values. This code may run before the `cout`.

Comment: Well... Ok. Thank you, guys. Adding all checks helped. It's really strange as for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @pashchenkoromak another possibility is that your output is delayed, if you want to force output to appear immediately try `cout << "test message" << endl;`

Comment: Anytime the compiler sees a chance to make code faster, it will probably take it. This often means that the output of the compiler looks like the source was thrown into a blender.